# Can One register namespace in django without adding a URL pattern?

Tags: python, django, django-cms

When creating an [apphook](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/app_integration.html) for the [photologue](http://django-photologue.readthedocs.org/en/3.0/) app into [django-CMS](http://django-cms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extending_cms/app_integration.html), I ran into trouble:

```
"photologue" is not a registered namespace
```

when trying to reverse an URL such as:

```
href="{% url 'photologue:pl-gallery-archive-year' date.year %}"
```

---

**My current Solution** is to add a 'foo' url pattern below the cms urls in urls.py so that foo will not ever be matched, but the photologue namespace is registered.

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),  # NOQA
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap',
        {'sitemaps':
             {
                 'cmspages': CMSSitemap,
                 'photologue_galleries': GallerySitemap,
                 'photologue_photos': PhotoSitemap,
             }}),

    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    url(r'^foo/', include('photologue.urls', namespace='photologue')),

)
```

cms_app.py:

```
class GalleriesApphook(CMSApp):
    name = _("Galleries Apphook")
    urls = ["photologue.urls"]
    app_name = "photologue"
apphook_pool.register(GalleriesApphook)
```

---

**My question is:** Is there a cleaner way to do this ? Like a "register_namespace" function in the django core ?

**EDIT**

I found something "slightly cleaner" in the [imagestore doc](http://imagestore.readthedocs.org/en/latest/djangocms.html). In order not to pollute urls they re-include the cms ones with the namespace.

```
url(r'^', include('cms.urls', namespace='imagestore'))
```

Comment: you did the correct thing by adding `app_name` to the `GalleriesApphook`. Additionally the the `app_name` the namespace is saved in the advanced settings on the cms page (next to the select box where you select the Apphook). It might be hidden as long as you only have added the Apphook once though (try adding it twice). Maybe that field contains a wrong/stale entry. It _should_ default to whatever you define as `app_name`, but maybe you didn't have that in the code yet when you initially added the apphook. This might also be a bug in django CMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I solved it with @stefanfoulis hint to add application instance name. I did not have app_name when starting this at first time.